# Missing textures in Dogfighter

Tags: dogfighter

I recently purchased [DogFighter](http://store.steampowered.com/app/42500/) on Steam and when I play the tutorial, I get missing textures. The screen's bottom is black and the top is white. However, I can still see the silhouette of the airplane in 3rd person view.

**My CYRI Analysis:**

CPU Minimum
You Have: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz

CPU Speed 
Minimum: 2.0 GHz Dual Core
You Have: 2.4 GHz
    PASS

RAM 
Minimum: 1 GB System RAM for Win XP, 2 GB for Vista/Windows 7 
You Have: 8.0 GB
    PASS

OS
Minimum: Windows XP (SP2 or more), Windows Vista (SP1 or more), Windows 7
You Have: Microsoft Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit
    PASS

Video Card
Minimum: 256 MB DirectX® 9.0c compliant supporting Pixel Shader 2.0 or better
You Have: Intel(R) HD Graphics
    PASS

Features: Minimum attributes of your Video Card

```
                         Required    You Have
 Video RAM               256 MB      1.7 GB
 Pixel Shader version    2.0         4.0
```

Sound Card
Minimum: Yes 
You Have: IDT High Definition Audio CODEC PASS

Free Disk Space 
Minimum: 600 MB or greater
You Have: 9.5 GB

Comment: Did you use "verify game integrity" option in steam?Missing textures are hardly result of a hardware issue.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Nothing.

Answer (score 3):

> You Have: Intel(R) HD Graphics PASS

Your GPU is very probably not supported.
Try updating your drivers.

If this is a notebook, search for the drivers from the notebook manufacturer, and not Intel.

Comment: My drivers are the latest from Intel.

Comment: Try searching from the latest ones from the manufacturer and *not* from Intel, as @Bora suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This game has it issues with anti aliasing especially if it is "forced" disabling/lowering  it in catalyst control center(ATI) works...

However not sure what controls you have with your graphic card,get in your graphic drivers software and try to find and lower AA options.Also turning off "triple buffering" may help.Or just try tweaking AA ingame,not tested but easiest.

Comment: There's no anti-aliasing options in the control panel. I will try tweaking it in the game options.